# Get current user name in the Git hub wiki page

Tags: java, git, github, wiki

Is there a way to get the connecter user name in a  github wiki page ?

Example

Welcome @connecterUser,

Please find here, the steps to install your environemet....
...
...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can use the GitHub REST API to do that [Here's the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user)

Comment: Hi Pedro,thanks for your answer,  i tried to test your solution in a wiki page, but no result.
Could you please provide me an example in a wiki page that work for you ? many thanks.